# Should i create a new route or have a variable to decide what operation to do?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am making a route for showing transactions to the users now for this, I have a route `transactions` but I am using this route for showing filtered transactions.

Now the question is should I make the same route for both fetching `All Transactions` and `Filtered Transactions`(It is self-broken into many categories) or should I have a different route for both of them ??

I mean will there be any performance enhancement if I will use any one of the approach or there will be no difference (which I think is).

Answer (score 0):

From a RESTFUL point of view, if your transactions are always splitted into categories, I think you could have

> /transactions

for all transactions and

> /category/:categoryId/transactions

for the transactions of one category.

But, if you are going to get transactions of several categories at once, probably it will be a better approach to have only

> /transactions?categories=categoryId1&categoryId2....

and with query parameters filtering by categories.